# Definition of a countable direct sum of subspaces of a Banach space

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space and $K\subseteq X$ a subspace. Let $\{H_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a countable collection of subspaces of $X$. Is it correct that $K=\bigoplus H_i$ iff every element $k\in K$ can be written uniquely as $k=\sum h_i$, where $h_i\in H_i$ for every $i\in I$? What is the exact definition of $\bigoplus H_i$ as a subspace of $X$?

Comment: Not quite. Usually the definition of direct sum requires the sum $\sum h_i$ to contain only finitely many nonzero elements.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a Banach space

Comment: @WillieWong I think that the condition is that the norm needs to be finite.

Comment: You'd do well to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules#Construction_for_an_arbitrary_family_of_modules and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product#Direct_product_of_modules